# How to get the value corresponding to solidity "tx.origin" in substrate ink?

Tags: substrate, rust-ink

- I'm implementing a contract that calls contract B from contract A.
- Now alice called contract B through contract A. I would like to know that it was alice who called this contract B. Can I get it?

```
let caller = self.env().caller();
```

- If you get caller in contract B like above, its value will be the contract address of contract A.

```
tx.origin
```

- I would like to get a value similar to solidity's "tx.origin".Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function does not exist in ink!. Reason is that is [considered unsafe and its addition a mistake in Solidity](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/683).

Comment: I do not know that Ethereum stop using "tx.origins".I recognized not enough studying. I study hard about Smart Contract. Thank you.